# Playcanvas with CSG

Tags: javascript, csg

I want to use library csg.js with Playcanvas game engine to make some curves
but don't know how to implement CSG (constructive solid geometry) in Playcanvas

Comment: How have you tried using csg.js so far? Where specifically do you run into trouble?

Comment: maybe this project with csg should match https://github.com/wei292224644/playcanvas-csg
but not sure about stability of this project but try